# Nextjs - Dynamic Imports - CSS Modules cannot be imported from within node_modules

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-css-modules

Struggling to wrap my head around this issue. I am using the [built in CSS modules](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css) for my components in Nextjs. When i lazy load my component that has a CSS module, I get the error `CSS Modules cannot be imported from within node_modules.`.

If I replace ${asset.name} with the value button, i.e `dynamic(() => import(@preamp/assets/Button))`, nextjs will compile.

1. The code will execute correctly if i dont use CSS modules. It will lazy load dynamic components in. Only when i add the file to the project.
2. If i hardcode the import path it compiles. I only have this issue when I use a template literal string.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const asset = { name: 'Button' };
const NewComponent = dynamic(() => import(`~/assets/${asset.name}`), {
    ssr: false,
});

export default function index() {
    return (
    <div className="grid-container">
        <div className="grid-x grid-margin-x">
        <div className="cell medium-6 large-6">
            <NewComponent />
        </div>
        <div className="cell medium-6 large-6">12/6/8 cells</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Test.module.css';

export default function Index() {
  return <div className={styles['btn-primary']}>Test Div</div>;
}
```

EDIT:
If I move the Test.module.css into a different folder, it will compile. I havent seen any documentation or reasoning why the CSS modules has to live in a particular area.

button.js updated

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '~/test/Test.module.css'; // <-- Moved into a different folder

export default function Index() {
  return <div className={styles['btn-primary']}>Test Div</div>;
}
```

Project specs:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.0",
    "next": "^12.0.3",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.43.4"
  },
```

Using node v14.17.3

Comment: I've never seen a "~" in an import path before, might that be causing a problem?

Comment: @MarkWilliams I dont believe so. I have an alias set in webpack where its a shortcut to `/src/` within my project. My code will compile fine if i replace my template literal with the name of the file.

Comment: @MygelBergstresser I am running on a similar issue where I am doing lazy loading of my component.  Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to post my answer. If you are going to use dynamic imports, then import paths themselves cannot be dynamic. I've added more information here.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/31271